# Wrapping vector tiles generated by geojson-vt

Tags: geojson, mapbox, vector-tiles

I've followed the example in [geojson-vt](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt), and am able to generate vector tiles from my geoJson source.  However, I can't read these tiles with [mapbox-gl-js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/) or [Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile](https://github.com/SpatialServer/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile) because I don't seem to be wrapping the tiles in a protocol buffer correctly.

Is there an example or package that automate this protobuf encoding of vector tiles?  I've looked at [geobuf](https://github.com/mapbox/geobuf), but that does not appear to be able to handle the tiles from geojson-vt.

Answer (score 3):

I have very similar problem, except I try to use angular-leaflet-directive. So far i couldn't find much about it. 
However,  please have a look at [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/Sumbera/raw/c67e5551b21c68dc8299/)  and the block itself. This may give you more ideas on how to link geojson-vt with leaflet.

Comment: That Leaflet example handles my huge GeoJSON file super fast! Any ideas how to get Mapbox GL JS to work that way? (My current platform uses Mapbox and is too slow w/ my GeoJSON file)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post, but if you happen here then you can direct yourself to vt-pbf, https://github.com/mapbox/vt-pbf. Does the trick.